# getJSON и Bigint

Tags: javascript, json

Есть некий API ([пример](http://api.ets2mp.com/player/76561198038877638)). В ответе есть параметр **steamID64**, который является идентификатором, тип данных - **BIGINT(17)**
Проблема в том что стандартная ф-ции ***$.getJSON***, ***$.parseJSON*** обрабатывают этот параметр не верно, возвращая округленный и не правильный результат. В PHP для этого есть параметр *JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING*, который преобразует число в строку, есть ли подобное в jquery? Или какие-то костыли для того чтобы решить эту проблему?

Вот пример для наглядности http://jsfiddle.net/5w3podm5/

Сейчас решаю вопрос кривым парсингом, но это как-то не правильно..

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://api.ets2mp.com/player/" + id,
  dataType : "text",
  success: function (data) {
    steamID = data.split("{")[2].split(",")[3].split(":")[1];
  }
});
```

Comment: Вы пробовали json-bigint ? Другого способа, чем использовать нестандартный парсер, очевидно, нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы парсить большие числа в качестве значений полей объекта десериализуемого из строки, требуется переопределить метод parseJSON так, чтобы он мог работать с большими числами(например JSON-парсер [sidorares/json-bigint](https://github.com/sidorares/json-bigint), который использует [MikeMcl/bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js)).

Вот модифицированный пример, который успешно работает: http://jsfiddle.net/5w3podm5/1/. В нём BigNumber естественно надо привести к строке, чтобы вывести:

```
data.response.steamID64.toString()
```